# Output contents of array in reverse in Java

Tags: java, arrays

My task is to make an array of size 20. Ask the user how many numbers he/she wants to enter. Put all those numbers in an array, then output that array in reverse. I've gotten it completed up to the "output that array in reverse" part.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Activity7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System. in );
        System.out.println("How many numbers?");
        int quantityOfNumbers = keyboard.nextInt();

        int[] numbers = new int[20]; //making an array the size of 20
        //0 - 19 (Valid values of the array)
        for (int subscript = 0; subscript < quantityOfNumbers; subscript++) {
            System.out.println("Enter number " + subscript);
            numbers[subscript] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Array Contents");
        for (int subscript = 19; subscript >= 0; subscript--) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are stuck on. The code shows you know how to iterate in reverse, how to access array elements, and how to print things. Just have a go.

Comment: It's unclear what you are stuck on because the code did not give the same output as you got.

Comment: I apologize. Provided output is an example of how I desire it to look. The code provided is what I have so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you are looking for. Could you specify a bit more? I'm completing your code to match the provided output anyway:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Activity7
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many numbers?");
    int quantityOfNumbers = keyboard.nextInt();

    int[] numbers = new int[20]; //making an array the size of 20

    //0 - 19 (Valid values of the array)
    for (int subscript = 0; subscript < quantityOfNumbers; subscript++)
    {
      System.out.println("Enter number " + subscript);
      numbers[subscript] = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Array Contents");
    for (int subscript = 19; subscript >= 0; subscript--)
    {
      if (subscript >= quantityOfNumbers) System.out.println("Subscript " + subscript + "is empty");
      else System.out.println("Subscript " + subscript + "contains " + numbers[subscript]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could the person downvoting please let me know at least how to improve the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the array with out the empty elements, you can use something like this. As 0 is the default int value, print it as long as it is not 0.

```
public static void reverse(int[] array)
    {
        for(int i=array.length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(array[i]!=0)
            {
                System.out.println(array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```